# SCSS if font size is greater than X, use Y

Tags: css, sass

Is it possible in SCSS? I need that, if any font is greater than 30px, use 22px (in media query for max width 480px)

Comment: How is Sass going to know this?  Sass only compiles to CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you know which selectors have a font-size of 30px or more, you just need to overwrite them inside a given media query.

```
.one{
    font-size: 50px;
}

.two{
    font-size: 33px;
}

@media (max-width: 480px){
    .one, .two{
        font-size: 22px;
    }
}
```

Comment: no, this is not right solution for me.. I have lots of classes for elements, I can't even find every class :D I did it with jquery